# Anytime I run php artisan serve, I get an error saying a requirement is missing

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have been trying to add some dependencies to my project of recent using composer. After adding adding some into the 
`require` 
array in composer.json, i got a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\uddy\3d-api\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\uddy\3d-api\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Please, what could cause this?

I've tried composer install and composer update

Comment: Have you tried 'composer dump-autoload' command ?
If yes, Can you please share your composer.json file? From the above information, it seems the issue is either with invalid json (typo error, such as missing comma etc.) or with incorrect file path for helpers.php file.

Comment: Thanks, @DakshimChhabra. Seems pretty good after generating new autoload files

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command:
*`composer dump-autoload`*
This command will clean up all compiled files and their paths.